# Why is the first half of the trip of the twin paradox not a paradox? (A simple experiment shows there is one.)

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, observers

**Experiment**

Two apparatus are labeled T1 and T2. The end of each apparatus is labeled A and B.  At end A is a clock and a computer, at end B is a switch and a data collector.  The apparatus are aligned as shown in the diagram below at t=0, T=0. The relative velocity between the two apparatus is v. For this example v=0.866_ such that γ =2.  c=1. The two coordinate frames shown are the rest frame for each apparatus.  In the left frame, T1 is at rest while T2 moves to the right. In the right frame T2 is stationary while T1 is moving to the left. Time in the T1 coordinate system is given the label t units, while time in the T2 coordinate system is given the label T units (this is normally given t’ but T is used for clarity). The length of the apparatus in the rest frame L=1 units. The length of the moving apparatus in each reference frame is shown in it’s contracted length (L=0.5 units), as would be seen in the reference frame. Both coordinate frames use the same X axis with the positive direction going towards the right.

[image: Experimental Set-up]

The vertical distance between the apparatus is much smaller than the length of the apparatus, so the time delays of the switch and data collection is small compared to the difference in time measured between start and finish times and the coordinate frame and prime coordinate frame. For this example they are collinear (shown separated for clarity).

Each apparatus calculates when the A end of the other apparatus reaches the B on its own end and records the time. (L/v).  When end A of the other apparatus reaches B it triggers a switch that collects the clock data from the other apparatus. (given zero vertical  separation delay time =0).

**Results**

The data each apparatus captures is:

T1: (x=-1, t=1.155,T=0.577)
T2: (x=1,T=1.155,t=0.577)

In both cases the apparatus at rest measures the clock on the moving apparatus as running slower than the at rest clock as expected.

Simultaneity:

At t=0, T=0, x=0  T1A and T2A are simultaneous, and the clocks are reset to zero.

At t=1.115, T1A,T1B and T2A are simultaneous

At T=1.115, T2A,T2B and T1A are simultaneous

The data is not collected simultaneously between the two final data recording events.  In each reference frame the collection of the data from the moving apparatus happens before the data collection on the rest apparatus due to length contraction of the moving apparatus in the rest frame.

In this experiment it occurs at:

T1: t=0.577.  When that event occurs the clock at T2F is T= 0.289, indicating even when the data was collected at different times it still shows the moving clock is running slower. It is not simultaneous because it is at x=0.5 in the T1 frame.  Due to symmetry the same thing occurs in T2 reference frame.

The claim in special relativity is that unless we can bring the two apparatus back together, which requires an acceleration of one or both apparatus, then we cannot compare the time of the clocks. I believe that misses a critical point.  At no point during the experiment was the clock t ever running slower than clock T in the T1 reference frame, or was clock T running slower than clock t in T2 reference frame. And that is where the inconsistency lies.

To highlight this, replace T1 with: Alice, T2 with : Bob (twins) and data is an image captured at each event. Alice and Bob are hyper aging twins. They age 60 years in 1.155 time units in their own rest frame.They will die at the age of 60 in there own reference frame. Alice and Bob are photographed at  t=0, T=0, when they are born. They are photographed at the two events outlined above.  There is photographic evidence that both twins aged faster than the other depending on the chosen reference frame.   When the photographs are brought together we see a conflict one is dead and one is alive. (The data can be transmitted at any rate into any other coordinate system, since the data is fixed)

In the T1 reference frame photos Alice looks like she is 60 (died) while Bob looks like he is 30 (alive), while in the T2 reference frame Alice looks like she is 30 (alive) and Bob looks like he is 60 (dead). The experiment is run over a fixed time interval. All the data collection occurred within 1.155 time units regardless of the reference frame.  The aging process is a real physical process and death is real. Looking at the pictures the data is inconsistent on who is alive or dead at the end of the experiment (t=1.155, T=1.155 units).

This issue has bugged me for years.  Can someone explain to me what is wrong with this analysis?

Comment: "When end T2A reaches T1B the switch is triggered and it records the clock data (0.577_ units) on T2A." If a switch is triggered e.g. via photon emission, then it means the events are not recorded as simultaneous since the act of emitting/triggering itself takes time and is thus subject to relativistic effects.

Comment: They point is, if you bring them both together that means they need to accelerate, if there is no acceleration there is no getting back together, and so no paradox,  each sees the other as aging slower, but they never meet. An observer that moves in a reference frame in which both move at the same speed, will see both aging at the same rate

Comment: What's "A"? What happened to "F"?  If the coordinates are S1 and S2, why are there primed coordinates? Also: why did you flip T1 and T2 in the two figures? Have you considered making the explanation a lot clearer?

Comment: What JEB said. *"while apparatus T2 lies along the X axis so TA"* Is TA supposed to be T2F?  In the earlier part of that paragraph you refer to the "x axis". Maybe you could use X1 and X2 to refer to these axes, rather than lower and upper case...

Comment: BTW, if you put a clock at each end of each apparatus, and synchronise the clocks in their rest frame, they will not be in synch in the other frame.

Comment: “If they could instantaneously be brought together,” then relativity would be wrong. I have voted to close as non-mainstream, because this is asking about an unphysical situation.

Comment: @rrb2022 There is no paradox. You say you have 'eliminated simultaneity', but that is incorrect and the cause of your misunderstanding. All your experiment shows is the symmetrical nature of time dilation. Suppose the twins are called A and B. In Twin A's frame, Twin A being 1.55 units of time older is simultaneous with Twin B being 0.577 units of time older, and vice versa in the other twin's frame.

Comment: @rrb2022. Your edited question simply underlines the point you are missing, which is the relativity of simultaneity. Both Alice and Bob die at the age of sixty. However, they are in different reference frames and they are far apart. In one frame Alice dying is simultaneous with Bob being thirty. In the other, Alice being thirty is simultaneous with Bob dying.

Answer (score 2):

> When they arrive and show each other the pictures(data) they took during the experiment, they will disagree who is older. Both twins will claim they are older and they will have pictures (data) to prove it

This is simply false. Age is a relativistic invariant, so all frames agree on it. They disagree on simultaneity, lengths, and durations, but they do not disagree on ages. In fact, not only is there no disagreement on ages at the end of the experiment, there is no disagreement at any event during the experiment.

As far as how it is not a paradox overall, the point is that all frames agree on the actual result of any measurement. They are all consistent with the actual experimental measurements. It is unsurprising that different measurements will produce different results, not paradoxical.